# How to decode file in Python-3.x?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, decoding

For my project I need to parse xml file. For doing this I use lxml. The file I need to parse has a cp1251 coding, but, ofcourse, for parsing it using lxml I need to decode it into utf-8, and I dont know how to do it. I tryed to serch something about this, but all solutions was for Python 2.7 or didnt work.
if try to write something like

```
inp = open("business.xml", "r", encoding='cp1251').decode('utf-8')
```

or

```
inp.decode('utf-8')
```

It gets

```
builtins.AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I have Python 3.2.
Any help is well, 
thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`open()` decodes the file *for you*. You are already receiving Unicode data.

For `lxml` you need to open the file in *binary* mode, and let the XML parser deal with encoding. Do not do this yourself.

```
with open("business.xml", "rb") as inp:
    tree = etree.parse(inp)
```

XML files include a header to indicate what encoding they use, and the parser adjusts to that. If the header is missing, the parser can safely assume UTF-8.